# CMAKE cannot identify .f90 as source code?

Tags: cmake, fortran

I am trying to use CMAKE to build a Fortran program

The test source files include: `TEST.cpp, A.f90, B.f90`

The CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

enable_language(Fortran)

aux_source_directory( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} SRC )

file(WRITE out.txt ${SRC} )
```

But the command `aux_source_directory` cannot identify the .f90 source files.

I have used  `enable_language(Fortran)`

But only the `TEST.cpp` file can be identified ( output in out.txt )

How could the .f90 source files be identified by `aux_source_directory`?

Comment: Please don't post text as images.

Comment: Images are removed

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
set(CMAKE_Fortran_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS f90)
```

From [cmake help](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_LANG_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS):

> CMAKE__SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS: Extensions of source files for the given language.
>     This is the list of extensions for a given languages source files.

Remember that, from [aux_source_directory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/aux_source_directory.html):

> It is tempting to use this command to avoid writing the list of
>   source files for a library or executable target. While this seems to
>   work, there is no way for CMake to generate a build system that knows
>   when a new source file has been added. Normally the generated build
>   system knows when it needs to rerun CMake because the CMakeLists.txt
>   file is modified to add a new source. When the source is just added to
>   the directory without modifying this file, one would have to manually
>   rerun CMake to generate a build system incorporating the new file.

So you may really only need to rerun cmake (I propose, remove all cmake generated files and rerun it on fresh). It's better to use `file(GLOB_RECURSE src *.f90)` or similar to find sources.

Comment: Very thankful ! " file(GLOB_....)" actually worked !  But is it always better to use this way to find sources?

Comment: I would deduce from the manual page, that yes. `aux_source_directory` is great for multiple `configure_file` calls.